# Linq To Xml: Is it possible to add XElement inline with search

Tags: linq-to-xml

New to Linq to Xml and having a play around with it.

I am carrying out a lot of operations similar to the following and I was wondering if it was possible in one statement:

```
    Dim childXEl As XElement = _
    <ChildElement></ChildElement>

    Dim results = _
    From parentXEl In xdoc.Descendants.<ParentXElement> 

    For Each xe As XElement In results
        xe.Add(childXEl)
    Next
```

I doubt this is possible but I am curious to know, can you add the xml in the search query thus making the for each loop unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well List(Of T) has a ForEach method taking an Action you can can do stuff like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim doc As XDocument = _
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <item>
            <foo>1</foo>
        </item>
        <item>
            <foo>2</foo>
        </item>
    </root>

    doc.Root.<item>.ToList().ForEach(AddressOf Add)
    doc.Save("output.xml")
End Sub

Sub Add(ByVal el As XElement)
    el.Add(<bar>test</bar>)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh that's prety neat, only problem for me is (although I didn't include it in my example) the element would not be applied to every item; there would be 'where' criteria in the search statement. Cheers though, thats good stuff to know!

Comment: You can apply the `ToList().ForEach()` to any `IEnumerable(Of T)` so of course using a `Where` first to filter is no problem.

Comment: Hmm... I can't figure out the syntax, any chance you could help me out? I know this is wrong but it's what I'm getting at `Dim xe As XElement = _ <foo>insert</foo> Dim results = _ From item In doc.Descendants.<item> Where item.<foo>.Value = 1 _ Select item.DescendantsAndSelf.ToList.ForEach(AddressOf Add(item, xe))`